# How to validate xml file with schema where schema is in string format

Tags: c#, xml

I need to validate a `XML` file against `XSD Schema` and the code worked fine. But currently, the schema is stored in string format in Database and the code to validate as shown below, is not working

```
 XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
 settings.Schemas.Add(null,"SchemaURL");
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader("XmlSchema"); 
XmlSchema xmlSchema;
xmlSchema = XmlSchema.Read(stringReader, null);
settings.Schemas.Add(xmlSchema);
```